Sharepoint 2010 Workflows in SP2016 wont start event after following KB article
Since the September update I have had workflows fail with event ID c42q0 I have read the KB article saying to add  the blow to web.config I have added it to the correct space however I still get the error
<authorizedType Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.WithKey" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />

It states to "If the type and assembly are safe, add the type to the authorized list in the Web.config file" My question is, what is the "type" for the below error?
Potentially malicious xoml node: <ns1:ReplaceListItemPermissionsActivity ListId="{ActivityBind ROOT,Path=__list}" x:Name="ID8" Roles="{ActivityBind ID27,Path=ReturnValue}" __Context="{ActivityBind ROOT,Path=__context}" Users="{ActivityBind ID22,Path=ReturnValue}" ListItem="{ActivityBind ROOT,Path=__item}" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:ns1="clr-namespace:Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.WithKey;Assembly=Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />

Any help appreciated
